# Create a MANET (mobile ad hoc network) with GNU/Linux Debian based hosts

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian

Do you have some recommendations on setting up a MANET using Debian based OS? 
I read some documentation after some web digging and I found that a basic setup would be creating an ad-hoc wireless network and some routing algorithms (implementation) as:

- OLSR (Optimized Link State Routing protocol):
- OSPF (Open Shortest Path First Routing)
- B.A.T.M.A.N. (Better Approach To Mobile Adhoc Networking)
- AODV (Ad hoc On-Demand Distance Vector)

I'm currently starting to test some of them (currently B.A.T.M.A.N :D) but haven't finish any of them. I got really inspired after seeing open-mesh.com project/products (it looks like they use ROBIN and B.A.T.M.A.N).

Thanks in advance!

Note: I'm a complete newbie at this so I apologize if some terms/concepts aren't correct. All feedback will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You also need to look at 802.11s mesh mode and OSPF-MDR from here: http://www.manet-routing.org/

The Boeing Quagga patches are perhaps the easiest to use and most flexible system, since you can route both IPv4 and IPv6, and extend OSPF to non-wireless parts of the network, using only one routing daemon and protocol.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. OSPF-MDR sounds very interesting. I'll give it a try.
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Check out CoCoCorp.com

Comment: Thanks John. CoCoCorp looks like a mature commercial product but I am looking for open source free alternatives to create the MANET. Although, is very interesting :)

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled on your question when looking for olsr.
I did something with ubuntu and olsrd to create an ad-hoc network.
I used three (didn't have more) ubuntu PC's (one as a gateway) and 1 Linksys WAP54G (with freifunk firmware).

It all worked pretty easy except for the fact that getting the right "Cell-ID"
was somewhat unpredictable on ubuntu. I got it all worked out here: http://www.kwalinux.nl/what-a-mesh/1129/